# How to trigger macro if a range of cells containing formulas linked to other sheets output a different value

Tags: excel, vba, triggers

I am running the following macro to apply conditional formatting on a range of cells. What I want is the macro to be triggered anytime those cell values change. The cell values are not changed manually (i.e. they aren't selected by a user and changed), they change automatically because they contain formulas linked to cells in other spreadsheets.

What is the most efficient of doing this?

```
  Sub TestSub3()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 5 To 27
    If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then

        For j = 2 To 16
            If Cells(i, j) = 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) 'light green fill
                Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'dark green font

            ElseIf Cells(2, 1) - Cells(i, 1) > 60 And Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red fill
                Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow font

            ElseIf Cells(2, 1) - Cells(i, 1) > 52 And Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) 'orange fill, black font

            ElseIf Cells(2, 1) - Cells(i, 1) > 45 And Cells(i, j) > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow fill, black font
            End If

        Next j

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not use conditional formatting?

Comment: @ScottCraner hey can you help me out? I'm not sure why newjenn's code isn't working and he's not responding. Thanks, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)" subroutine to perform change function. Paste the below code in the Microsoft excel object-->sheetname place. Look into the attached picture too

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 5 To 27
    If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then

        For j = 2 To 16

        'Debug.Print Cells(i, j)

            If Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) 'light green fill
                Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'dark green font

            ElseIf (Cells(2, 1).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value) > 60 And Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red fill
                Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow font

            ElseIf (Cells(2, 1).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value) > 52 And Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) 'orange fill, black font

            ElseIf (Cells(2, 1).Value - Cells(i, 1).Value) > 45 And Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow fill, black font
            End If

        Next j

    End If

End Sub
```

You can also look into link for your reference[image] 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: Look at the remarks on the page you provided, this will not fire.  The OP says that the cells contain formula and are not changed manually. It needs to be the calculate event

Comment: @newjenn in your screenshot you have the code pasted in module 3 instead of sheet1 code, was that an accident? I am supposed to paste this in the sheet code where I want it to operate right? Not save it as a module

Comment: You need to paste in sheet1 not in module

Comment: @newjenn it is not working. When new data is entered into the sheets this sheet is linked to and its cell values are recalculated, the macro doesn't seem to run.

To clarify, I need this subroutine to be activated anytime a change is made to 2 spreadsheets in my workbook. The only time they change is when the spreadsheets they are linked to (via formulas) are changed. 

What I did was paste the above code into the code sheet for both sheets I want the macro to run in. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: @RG1of2 change the top line to `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`  The line that newjenn gave goes in the `ThisWorkbook` object.  So, in the sheet object like he explained it needs to be named different.

Comment: It worked! Thanks newjenn and scott, you guys are awesome